# Lotus Domino: Migrating code changes to production, in clustered environment

Tags: cluster-computing, lotus-domino

We have  clustered environment for domino server on production. I want to migrate code changes from staging to production. I have not changed signature for any of the old functions in the script library, but I have added a new function in the script library which is being called by a specific agent. All works well in staging. Now I want to transfer these changes to the cluster(consists of two servers) in production.
If I copy paste the new function(in script library) and also the changed agent which call this new function  to one of the server in production, will these code changes automatically be replicated to the other server?. I mean what's the best way to migrate these changes?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data and *design elements* get replicated immediately between clustered servers. So, if you change an agent or script library on first server the second server gets changes only seconds after.

Sometimes you get an error message "Error loading USE or USELSX module" after changing a script library. The error occurs if you call an agent or open a form which uses the script library. In this case, you have to recompile the agent or form to work the design elements properly with the new internal structure of the script library.

This error won't probably appear in your case as your changes work well in development environment. You should test all parts of your application which use the changed script library though to make sure it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to make it seamless:

1) make your staging database a master template, and
2) make your production database inherit the design from that master template.

Then, on one of your production databases, Application > Refresh Design, and it'll ask what server to refresh the design from.  Make this your staging server.

It's particularly important to recompile all LotusScript if you don't do this; otherwise, you may end up with "Type mismatch on external name: ".  If you do this on your staging server, both the uncompiled and the compiled LotusScript design documents will be part of the design refresh, and it'll make things a lot easier.

Note that all clients must completely close and reopen the database to recognize any code changes.  (This means 'the database tab itself, as well as any documents that are open from that database'.)

Comment: This is how I would do it. Working with templates has so much advantages: possibility of versioning (by using different templates), rollback, no "forgotten" design elements when manually copy pasting, etc.